# Apache virtualhost configuration

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I am tring to set two virtual host (example.com.conf  and test.com.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@test.com
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias www.test.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/public_html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

The problem is that if I go on localhost in my browser it is shown the website www.example.com. If I type localhost/test.com there is error not found. My goal should be to address both website with localhost/example.com and localhost/test.com.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use the [ServerPath directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) for apache, in your case something like this should work:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
# primary vhost
DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "." "/var/www/example.com/public_html"
# ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com/public_html"
ServerName localhost
ServerPath "/example/"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^(/sub1/.*)" "/var/www/example$1"
# ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/test.com/public_html"
ServerName localhost
ServerPath "/test/"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^(/sub2/.*)" "/var/www/test$1"
# ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The first Vhost would be so that localhost defaults to example.com page.

Comment: The ip that you set should be my localhost ip?

Comment: example path works but test path throw error not found. I didn't add the first vhost, is not important right?

Comment: it's just to default to example

Comment: Ok I didn't add the primary host. I don't know why test path doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

if you want to browse to these folders under any virtual host, like http://localhost/test.com, then you simply need an [`alias` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) inside a location tag appended to the end of any active virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Location "/example.com">
    Alias "/var/www/example.com/public_html"
</Location>

<Location "/test.com">
    Alias "/var/www/test.com/public_html"
</Location>
```

Or you can put it inside the virtual host if you don't want it available anywhere else

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
          <Location "/example.com">
              Alias "/var/www/example.com/public_html"
          </Location>

          <Location "/test.com">
              Alias "/var/www/test.com/public_html"
          </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So I don't need to create two separated conf file but just add this locate tag to the main conf inside sites-available folder?

Comment: yup. I'm curious why you're not directly accessing them with http://www.example.com and http://test.com since your other virtual hosts are valid for their own domains

Comment: I really don't know

Comment: I tried your solution but there is an error that says alias is not allowed

Comment: it said alias is not allowed on the console when restarting the web server, or when you browsed to it in the browser?

Comment: in terminal when i restart the server